# Why is there no executable when publishing my console application

Tags: c#, .net, console, visual-studio-2017

When I publish my console application, the target folder only contains these files

```
ADVWKSPConsole.application
Application Files
autorun.inf
setup.exe
```

And the `Application Files` folder doesn't contain my `.exe`

I can see that the `.exe` is generated in the bin folder, but its not sent to the publish location ... Why?

I need to run the application from a scheduled task, and this is not working when telling the task to run the `ADVWKSPConsole.application` manifest (even from a `.bat`)

I can see in my publish properties in VS:

[image]

What gives? Why is this so annoying? All I want is an executable file published as my console application why isn't that the default!?

Comment: Then don't publish, just build. When you build the release version, all the files you need will be under \bin\Release

Comment: @RufusL The exe is in `bin` by default, and I could copy it over with a post publish/build script, but can't VS handle that for me? do people not generally deploy executables?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're looking for. What's wrong with running `setup.exe` then?

Comment: My ideal scenerio: Publish from VS copies an exe to the server. The server will have a scheduled task which executes that `.exe`. Currently I only have the manifest copied over, and that doesn't work from a scheduled task (annoyingly).

Comment: So `setup.exe` is not there? Weird. I don't know much about publishing, but that works for me. I suppose you could set your project to build the release version to a shared location (project properties -> (set configuration to release) -> build -> output -> output path -> \\server\share\). But maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @RufusL setup.exe is there, but I thought that was some kind of installer(since its called setup..) But it seems that after it does its thing, it actually runs the application so I could point my task at that. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: You can go ahead and answer it if that worked for you. Publishing isn't really something I know much about, so you may have figured out more than me by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rufus' suggestions in the comments, I realised that the scheduled task works when pointing it at `Steup.exe`, which is pretty unintuitive in my opinion, as that looks like an installer not the application itself..

What I ended up doing is

1. Point the **Build** path in Properties -> Publish to the location on the server
2. Changed the **Publish** path to some other folder
3. Now the .exe sits in the **Build** folder on the server and I can just point the task at that